# 1px broken line under the 1st tab in my css menu

Tags: html, css, tabs

I need your help.

I have a CSS tabbed menu with a little javascript support, however, it appears that under my first menu item there is a broken 1px line, how can this be fixed?

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabbed Content</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var g=function(a){if(a&&a.stopPropagation)a.stopPropagation();else window.event.cancelBubble=true;var b=a?a:window.event;b.preventDefault&&b.preventDefault()},d=function(a,c,b){if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(c,b,false);else a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+c,b)},a=function(c,a){var b=new RegExp("(^| )"+a+"( |$)");return b.test(c.className)?true:false},j=function(b,c,d){if(!a(b,c))if(b.className=="")b.className=c;else if(d)b.className=c+" "+b.className;else b.className+=" "+c},h=function(a,b){var c=new RegExp("(^| )"+b+"( |$)");a.className=a.className.replace(c,"$1");a.className=a.className.replace(/ $/,"")},e=function(){var b=window.location.pathname;if(b.indexOf("/")!=-1)b=b.split("/");var a=b[b.length-1]||"root";if(a.indexOf(".")!=-1)a=a.substring(0,a.indexOf("."));if(a>20)a=a.substring(a.length-19);return a},c="mi"+e(),b=function(b,a){this.g(b,a)};b.prototype={h:function(){var b=new RegExp(c+this.a+"=(\\d+)"),a=document.cookie.match(b);return a?a[1]:this.i()},i:function(){for(var b=0,c=this.b.length;b<c;b++)if(a(this.b[b].parentNode,"selected"))return b;return 0},j:function(b,d){var c=document.getElementById(b.TargetId);if(!c)return;this.l(c);for(var a=0;a<this.b.length;a++)if(this.b[a]==b){j(b.parentNode,"selected");d&&this.d&&this.k(this.a,a)}else h(this.b[a].parentNode,"selected")},k:function(a,b){document.cookie=c+a+"="+b+"; path=/"},l:function(b){for(var a=0;a<this.c.length;a++)this.c[a].style.display=this.c[a].id==b.id?"block":"none"},m:function(){this.c=[];for(var c=this,a=0;a<this.b.length;a++){var b=document.getElementById(this.b[a].TargetId);if(b){this.c.push(b);d(this.b[a],"click",function(b){var a=this;if(a===window)a=window.event.srcElement;c.j(a,1);g(b);return false})}}},g:function(f,h){this.a=h;this.b=[];for(var e=f.getElementsByTagName("a"),i=/#([^?]+)/,a,b,c=0;c<e.length;c++){b=e[c];a=b.getAttribute("href");if(a.indexOf("#")==-1)continue;else{var d=a.match(i);if(d){a=d[1];b.TargetId=a;this.b.push(b)}else continue}}var g=f.getAttribute("data-persist")||"";this.d=g.toLowerCase()=="true"?1:0;this.m();this.n()},n:function(){var a=this.d?parseInt(this.h()):this.i();if(a>=this.b.length)a=0;this.j(this.b[a],0)}};var k=[],i=function(e){var b=false;function a(){if(b)return;b=true;setTimeout(e,4)}if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",a,false);else if(document.attachEvent){try{var f=window.frameElement!=null}catch(g){}if(document.documentElement.doScroll&&!f){function c(){if(b)return;try{document.documentElement.doScroll("left");a()}catch(d){setTimeout(c,10)}}c()}document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){document.readyState==="complete"&&a()})}d(window,"load",a)},f=function(){for(var d=document.getElementsByTagName("ul"),c=0,e=d.length;c<e;c++)a(d[c],"tabs")&&k.push(new b(d[c],c))};i(f);return{}})()</script>
    <link href="tabcontent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#view1">Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#view2">Comments</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabcontents">
            <div id="view1">
                <b>Lorem Issum</b>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>

            </div>
            <div id="view2">
                <b>Switch to other templates</b>
                <p>Open this page with Notepad, and update the CSS link to:</P>
                <p>template1 ~ 6.</p>                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
ul.tabs
{
    padding: 7px 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left; /*set to left, center, or right to align the tabs as desired*/
}

ul.tabs li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right:3px; /*distance between tabs*/
}

ul.tabs li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-color:#B7B7B7;
    color: rgb(11,63,113);
    outline:none;
    background: rgb(223,223,223);
}

ul.tabs li a:visited
{
    color: #000;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
}

ul.tabs li.selected a, ul.tabs li.selected a:hover
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}


ul.tabs li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


div.tabcontents
{
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: What if you add `margin-bottom: -1px;` to `#tabs`?

Comment: Did you include the browser resets? Something like `* { margin:0; padding: 0;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LAhFM/)**

You need to use this CSS:

```
ul.tabs li.selected a, ul.tabs li.selected a:hover
{
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-top:8px;
}
```

The reason is because for the selected list item, you've set the border to 1px etc..then the color of the bottom border to white. The line of the bottom border is extending over the container border- giving the appearance of a 1px gap. By offsetting the bottom of the selected class by -1px, removing the border at the bottom and increasing the top padding, this gap is removed.

Comment: I can see how this would work (+1), but should it be necessary? What about browser prefixes or pseudo elements?

Comment: I just saw your updated answer. Thanks for the explanation. Besides cross browser compatibility, why not use box-sizing?

Comment: Thanks very much. Works like a charm. I didn't know a border could ever have a -1 =\ This is new to me!

Comment: Im stuck using IE7 at work to conform my page to. IT is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Set the li and a elements to `display:inline-block`